# How can all clients be easily cleared from Sensu?

Tags: sensu

I'm trying to clear all of the clients and alerts from Sensu, but they keep coming back.

With large numbers of clients, Uchiwa is unable to efficiently or reliably delete them all.

I have also tried deleting all of the keys in Redis while `sensu-api` and `sensu-server` services are stopped, but once they are restarted, all of the clients come back, including clients that don't exist and are failing their keepalive checks.

Do I have to empty all of the RabbitMQ queues as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Uchiwa or API or CLI to remove the client(s). If you want to delete all clients, use `Uchiwa->Clients`, select all clients and then select `Delete` from `Actions` dropdown.

[image]

[image]